# Throttling database calls

Tags: c#, rest, architecture

At my current company (C#), we are moving to a microservice architecture with properly split datastores, but that's a lot of work that's going to take a fair amount of time and we currently have a pressing issue with our database. At the moment, several sites/apis calls into it and it's not uncommon for the database calls to start failing due to the system being overloaded. Is there a good way/official pattern for throttling your calls to a datastore either on the datastore side or in a given api?

Thanks!

Comment: This article gives some decent overview and ideas you might build into your application:
https://www.dataversity.net/how-to-handle-throttling-in-cloud-databases/#
TLDR; perhaps you could add in throttling on the client side (retry logic/wait until not busy) because it's cheaper and more scalable.

Comment: Throttling means you are exceeding your capacity. 
for the current situation, you can put a timer for call delay or you can check out memory cache for that kind of data which do not need changing a lot frequently and you are getting it in every call so you can get it from c# Memory cache it will make difference too.